# Why do we need multiplication in this condition and how could this be replaced with addition?

Tags: java

My friend sent me a simple java math task to find if any 2 numbers of 3 inserted are even. I did it but then could not understand how it worked.

I sum all three numbers and then find remainder of division of their sum. It works but if all numbers are odd it shows true anyway. So I needed one more condition.
And I wondered why only multiplication works here, why there is no way to add numbers and change the condition to get the correct result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  int firstNumber = scanner.nextInt();
   int secondNumber = scanner.nextInt();
   int thirdNumber = scanner.nextInt();

   int sumOfNumbers = firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber;
    boolean if2NumbersEven = sumOfNumbers % 2 != 0 &&
            // Why is only multiplication needed here, addition does not work
            firstNumber * secondNumber % 2 == 0; 
            
    System.out.println(if2NumbersEven);
}
```

P.S. I understand how dumb the question is, I have spent hours learning java today and my brain really stopped working.

Comment: I ran this in PowerShell and it worked perfectly. Not sure I understand the problem you're having.

Comment: Did you ask your friend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only use `1` and `2` for odd and even, because it's easier to understand.

The first part of the condition you did already figure out:

```
sumOfNumbers % 2 != 0

// 1+1+1 % 2 = 1 => true
// 1+1+2 % 2 = 0 => false
// 1+2+2 % 2 = 1 => true
// 2+2+2 % 2 = 0 => false
```

It's `true` if there are zero or two even numbers.

The second condition is needed to get rid of the "three uneven numbers" (= zero even numbers) case:

```
firstNumber * secondNumber % 2 == 0

// 1*1 % 2 = 1 => false
// 1*2 % 2 = 0 => true
// 2*2 % 2 = 0 => true
```

As you can see: This condition is only `true` if there's at least one or two even numbers. ("at least" because the third number has no impact on the result of this condition, it can be even or odd).
And if one, two or three numbers are even, then it's impossible that all three are odd (= it's impossible that there's no even number).

If you combine both you get something like this:

```
            | 3 even | 2 even | 1 even | 0 even
-----------------------------------------------
1.condition | false  | true   | false  | true
-----------------------------------------------
2.condition | true   | true   | true   | false
-----------------------------------------------
result      | false  | true   | false  | false
```

---

If you use addition instead of multiplication, it won't work:

```
firstNumber + secondNumber % 2 == 0

// 1+1 % 2 = 0 => true
// 1+2 % 2 = 1 => false
// 2+2 % 2 = 0 => true
```

Now the condition would be `true` if "at least 2 numbers are odd". And this can mean that all three are odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can just **sum the rest of the division by 2** of the 3 numbers. If it returns 1, it means that exactly 2 of the 3 numbers are even. Like this:

```
int restsOfDivisionsBy2 = (firstNumber % 2) + (secondNumber % 2) + (thirdNumber % 2);

boolean if2NumbersEven = (restsOfDivisionsBy2 == 1);
```

Comment: This tells you the count of odd numbers, not even numbers

Answer (score 0):

The sum of all mods tells you exactly how many odd numbers you have.

```
int allMods = firstNumber%2 + secondNumber%2 + thirdNumber%2
```

Proof (in PowerShell)

```
PS C:\windows\system32> 
$firstNumber  = 1
$secondNumber = 2
$thirdNumber  = 5
$firstNumber%2 + $secondNumber%2 + $thirdNumber%2

2

PS C:\windows\system32> 
$firstNumber  = 1
$secondNumber = 3
$thirdNumber  = 5
$firstNumber%2 + $secondNumber%2 + $thirdNumber%2
3

PS C:\windows\system32> 
$firstNumber  = 1
$secondNumber = 2
$thirdNumber  = 5
$firstNumber%2 + $secondNumber%2 + $thirdNumber%2
2

PS C:\windows\system32> 
$firstNumber  = 1
$secondNumber = 2
$thirdNumber  = 4
$firstNumber%2 + $secondNumber%2 + $thirdNumber%2
1
```

The count of all numbers minus this resulting allMods number will give you the count of all even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For three numbers `a, b, c` let's look at the value of the expression `(a + b + c) % 2` for differing numbers of odd values:

```
# odd     (a+b+c)%2
  0           0
  1           1
  2           0 
  3           1
```

So we can narrow down the cases to 1 and 3 just by checking for `(a + b + c) % 2 != 0`. Now we need to distinguish between one odd and all three odd.

Two odd numbers multiplied together give an odd result - in all other cases the result is even. So, if we pick any two of the three numbers and find that their product is even then at least one of them must be even, in which case all three cannot be odd, and we've identified the case of interest.

```
if2NumbersEven(a, b, c) = (a + b + c) % 2 == 1 and (a * b) % 2 == 0
```